# Python list of lists - make all sublists same size

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of 74 items, each of these items contain a list 1-10 items themselves.

My goal was to fill in any sublists that had less than 10 subitems to make them have 10 subitems each.  The way I thought you did this was with `zip_longest` from `itertools`.  However, when I do this, the resulting structure is 10 x 74 and I was expecting it to be 74 x 10.  So this has done two things: it has filled in my shorter sublists which I wanted, but it has also performed a transpose operation at the same time.  I only wanted the former.

So if I ran `zip_longest` on the output of `zip_longest`, this could perhaps give me the final output, but it seems I am missing something because why do I want to take 2 transposes?  There has to be a cleaner way of padding these sublists.

This is the code I have

```
from itertools import zip_longest
zl = zip_longest(*master_results, fillvalue='')
for z1 in zl2:
    print(len(z1))
zl2 = zip_longest(*zl, fillvalue='')
for z2 in zl2:
    print(len(z2))
```

which gives me 10 printouts of 74 for the first for loop and 74 printouts of 10 for the 2nd for loop.

Comment: Instead of itertools I would use numpy for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62459704/np-reshape-with-padding-if-there-are-not-enough-elements

Comment: Your example doesn't run, but something like this appears to be the right shape, if I understood your question [list(x) for x in zip(*zip_longest(*master_results, fillvalue=''))] If you want a full answer, I'll have to post my own sample data. Also, I didn't handle trimming longer lists because those presumably don't appear in your data.

Comment: If I just delete the erroneous part, the zl2 lengths in your example code appear to be correct ... using some sample data I made up, obviously. You can just use zip(*) on the unzip step, since the lengths are already fixed.

Comment: *"My goal was to fill in any sublists"* - Why? With what does that help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and straightforward approach.

```
for sublist in master_results:
    if len(sublist) < 10:
        sublist.extend([""]*(10-len(sublist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With a list-comprehension

```
size = 6
filled_tail = ['']

# test list
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]

[subl + filled_tail*(size-len(subl)) for subl in lst]
#[[1, 2, '', '', '', ''], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ''], [8, 9, '', '', '', '']]
```